# onListItemClick add item to ListView in another activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am very sorry if this question already exists, but I couldn't find any answer to my problem. The idea of my application is a Shopping List. The user can see a list of food and on clicking on an item, it should automatically be added to a list.

What I already have is a ListView generated from an xml-file in a raw folder. This is my food, I haven't stored it in a SQLite Database.
What I want to do now is that when I click on an item in this list, it's added to a ListView in another Activity called "ShoppingList.java". It shouldn't open immediately, so the user has the possibility to add more items.

Now, when I click on an item, it's added to a TextView called "selection" in the same Activity on the top of the screen. 
How is it possible to add an item from one Activity to another one? 
Thank you very much for your help!

```
    public class FishOk extends ListActivity {
    TextView selection;
    ArrayList<String> items=new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
     super.onCreate(icicle);
     setContentView(R.layout.foodok_list);
     selection=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.selection);

    try {
     InputStream in=getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.fish);
     DocumentBuilder builder=DocumentBuilderFactory
                            .newInstance()
                            .newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc=builder.parse(in, null);
     NodeList words=doc.getElementsByTagName("product");

    for (int i=0;i<words.getLength();i++) {
    items.add(((Element)words.item(i)).getAttribute("value"));
    }

    in.close();
    }

    catch (Throwable t) {
     Toast
     .makeText(this, "Exception: "+t.toString(), 2000)
     .show();
    }

    ListView lstView = getListView(); 
 lstView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
 lstView.setTextFilterEnabled(true); 

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                              items));
    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position,
              long id) {
     selection.setText(items.get(position).toString());
    }

        public void onClick(View view) {
            ListView lstView = getListView(); 

            String itemsSelected = "Selected items: \n"; 
            for (int i=0; i<lstView.getCount(); i++) {
                if (lstView.isItemChecked(i)) {
            itemsSelected += lstView.getItemAtPosition(i) + "\n"; 
        }
    }
            Toast.makeText(this, itemsSelected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

        }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Be specific what you did? What you want to achieve and what problem you are facing.

Comment: i'm sorry for being unspecific. the whole idea of the application is to create a shopping list. the user can see a list of food and on clicking on it, it should be automatically added to a shopping list. what i have done so far, is creating a list. the items are stored in an xml-file, not in an sql-database. here, it's called "fish.xml". i want now, that on clicking on an item in this list, the item is added to a listview in a new activity. now, when i click on an item, it appears at the top, in a textview called "selection", but that's not what i want. i hope it's clearer now! thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Activity** is a **window where** you can put your **UI stuff so** that **user can interact with the application**.

Now, for **using the data** in the activities across the application, you have to **use either Collections or Database**.

But as per **your requirement**, I think you should use **Collections**.

- **Maintain an Arraylist or a HashTable**  according to your data.
- **Pass that data from one activity to other.**

OR

- **Maintain a singleton class** and **update the data in that class**. **Access the data from other activities.**

I hope this helps you.

Comment: i am still trying to figure it out because i'm quite a newbie! to pass the data, would it be correct to use a "putExtra" method?

Comment: thank you very much! i will keep trying and will give you an "accepted"!

Answer (score 1):

Adding an item to the `ListView` of an `Activity` which isn't visible to the user and doesn't yet exist makes no sense. You should have a place where you'll store the data, it can be a SQLite database, a plain text file, or `SharedPreferences` if there's not much data. When you're clicking on a `Button` inside your current `Activity` you should store the information to your data storage, and then retrieve it to populate the `ListView` when the second `Activity` starts. Hope this helps.